# Stopping carousel on last slide on twitter bootstrap v2.3.0

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have been searching around and can't seem to get a clear answer.  I have 5 images and I want it to stop at the end of the last slide.

Here is the code:

```
<!-- begin: carousel -->
        <section id="carousel">
              <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                  <div class="item active">
                    <img src="img/slider/fake1.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h4>First Thumbnail label</h4>
                      <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/slider/fake2.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h4>Second Thumbnail label</h4>
                      <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/slider/fake3.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h4>Third Thumbnail label</h4>
                      <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/slider/fake4.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h4>Third Thumbnail label</h4>
                      <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="item">
                    <img src="img/slider/fake5.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                      <h4>Third Thumbnail label</h4>
                      <p>Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula ut id elit.</p>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </section>
        <!-- end: carousel -->
```

and here is my JS

```
<script>
  !function ($) {
    $(function(){
      // carousel demo
      $('#myCarousel').carousel(
        {
            interval: 3000,
            pause: 'hover'
        }
      )
    })
  }(window.jQuery)
</script>
```

thanks in advance..

I tried to add `cycle: true` and `clycle: 'true'` but it still goes and the third slide goes twice more (obviously for slide 4 and 5) then it goes back to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Get a hook on carousel's 'slid' event (fires after sliding) and when the last slide is active pause the carousel, like:

```
$('#myCarousel').bind('slid', function(e) {
    var c = e.target;
    if($(c).find('.item:last').hasClass('active')) {
        $('#myCarousel').carousel('pause');
    }
});
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xQupa/)

Comment: @Shail, just added a basic fiddle

Comment: Thanks. I actually ran across that this morning.  Its weird though because it doesnt do it for me on IE8.  Not sure if its compatible with IE9 since I dont have it on my machine.  anyone else know why it doesnt work on IE8?  It just doesn't stop the cycle.

Comment: Good point. I am on a mac so can't test this on IE. I'll check on the home machine.